# Update specific column equal to other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, opencart

I have 2 tables, which one of them is appen to other.
I'm using opencart, and need to update title to all products from specific category.

Example:
**oc_product_description**

```
product_id
language_id
name

1
3
T-backs model 887 Róża

2
3
T-backs model 912 Róża

3
3
Push up model 3173 Róża
```

**oc_product_to_category**

```
category_id
product_id

1
1

2
1

3
1
```

And I can't imagine what query I should use..

```
UPDATE oc_product_description
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'T-backs model', 'BACK')
WHERE product_id = SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE category_id = 54;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE oc_product_description
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'T-backs model', 'BACK') WHERE product_id IN ( SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE category_id = 54 );

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then a product_id you should use where product_id  in and not where product_id =

```
UPDATE oc_product_description
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'T-backs model', 'BACK') 
WHERE product_id in ( SELECT product_id 
            FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE category_id = 54);
```